# Get and display data from API using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

So guys, I need to get this API data: https://api.github.com and put it on a HTML file.

So here is the JavaScript code I'm writing:

```
     async function getData() 
  {
    //await the response of the fetch call
    let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com');
    //proceed once the first promise is resolved.
    let data = await response.json()
    //proceed only when the second promise is resolved
    let newData = data.results;
    return newData;
  }
//call getData function
getData()
.then(function(result){
    $.each(result, (index, user) => {
      $('#character').append(`
        <div class='card'>
          <img
            src=${user.image}
            alt=''
            class='round-img'
          />
          <h4 class='card-name'>${user.name}</h4>
          <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
            <label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle">
              <i class='fas fa-chevron-down'> </i>
            </label>
          </input>
        </div>
      `)
    });
})
```

So I'm getting the users info, but I need to display it on a list with limited quantity of users per page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an external library, then Data Table is one good library that will give you search, filter, sort, and pagination capability. you just neet to create the table and pass the id of that table to the Data Table library. It will take care of your requirements. You can set max items per page.

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of .each(), loop 'result' with a for loop.

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<(offset+(page*8)+1);i++){
  //use result[i] in your html
}
```

offset if how many records you are in (so 0 for first page)
page is page num (so 1 for first page)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/) you provided.

> The API will automatically paginate the responses. You will receive up to 20 documents per page.

The `info` field on the response will give you some useful information about the dataset, including how many pages there are, the next page & the count of documents.

```
info: {
  count: 493,
  pages: 25,
  next: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2",
  prev: ""
}
```